# How can I show alert on my timer when timer finished

Tags: javascript, css, timer

I am using timer in JavaScript, I want that when my timer is finish it show me alert but right now my timer restart again with same time can any one guide me. how can I show alert in my timer when it finish.

```js
// properties
var count = 0;
var counter = null;

window.onload = function() {
  initCounter();
};

function initCounter() {
  // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
  count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
}

function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
  if (window.localStorage) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
  }

  return val;
}

function getLocalStorage(key) {
  return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
}

function timer() {
  count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
  if (count == -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }

  var seconds = count % 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  minutes %= 60;


  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds + "  seconds left to complete this transaction"; // watch for spelling
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Um, when it is done add an alert?.... aka the clearInterval line....

Comment: to precise epascarello's comment, which wan be vague to understand for a beginner: The operation that represents the end of your timer is this one `clearInterval(counter);`. The "return" just below terminates the function. So if you have any action to do like an `alert`, the best place is just before this `return;`

Comment: Thank you sir, but its worked only once and it going in minus like (-1,-2 ) etc   and I want that when it reach 0 then alert show me "Time Out" and timer will  not go in minus.

Comment: the count shouldn't go below `-1`, don't remove the `clearInterval` line or else your timer will continue to run endlessly. If you want the count to stop at `0` instead of `-1`, replace `if (count == -1) {` by `if (count == 0) {` (on my part i always prefer to use `if (count < 1) {` in the impossible case that one step never occurs, but that's a bit paranoid lol)

Comment: You are looping over 60 second cycles. The screen will show 60 ... all the way to 0, then go back to 60, but the actual count will be 1000 ... 960 ... 920 ... 860 ... etc, until it reaches -1 and then your seconds counter in the screen will stop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is related to `count`. You set it to `1000`. So you will have to wait `1000 min` before your function `clearInterval(timer)` is executed. You can try the following:

**Timer restarts after reloading the page**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // properties
  var count = 0;
  var counter = null;

 window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

 function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    count = 6000;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

 function timer() {
    count = count -1;

   var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;

   if(seconds === 0)
    {
  clearInterval(counter);
                alert("terminated");
        }
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =  seconds +  "  seconds left to complete this transaction"; // watch for spelling
  }
 </script>


 <div id="timer"></div>
```

**Timer remains unchanged even after restart**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // properties
  var count = 0;
  var counter = null;

 window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

 function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    if(!count || count < 0)
    {
        count = 1000;
    }
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

 function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

   return val;
  }

 function getLocalStorage(key) {
    return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
  }

 function timer() {
    count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);

   var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;

   if(seconds === 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
        alert("terminated");
        }
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =  seconds +  "  seconds left to complete this transaction"; // watch for spelling
  }
 </script>


 <div id="timer"></div>
```

*It is not a snippet as the first one, because `localstorage` are disabled in snippet of `stackoverflow`*

Comment: This time it show me alert but but it show me this message "0 seconds left to complete this transaction" my timer is not starting this time Its fix on 0.

Comment: Yes, I have just realized it. Let me fix it

Comment: Thank-you very much sir, Its Working but my one more query is that when I refresh the page Its start from beginning, Sir can you suggest me that if I will refresh the page It should start from previous page which timer counted.

Comment: @Ginni, do not forget to accept the answer and upvote it!