# Recursive timer not pausing correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a Timer built to Cycle through JSON data that is being fed to it via  a variable. At the moment, when I click the pause button, the countdown pauses correctly, but as soon as I click the button again the timer starts from the first set of data instead of from where it was paused. How can I avoid this from happening and get the pause function to work correctly?

```js
    var label = document.getElementById("exerciseLabel");
    var button = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
    var counter = document.getElementById("exerciseCounter");
    var routine = document.getElementById("info");
    var current = 0;
    var playing = false;
    var countdownTimer = null;
    var workout =
    {
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in place",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    };
    
    // LOOPING TIMER FUNCTION
    // Initialise virtual trainer.
    init();
    
    /**
    * Bind loop start to click on button.
    *
    * @return {void}
    */
    function init()
    {
      loop();
      button.addEventListener("click", toggle);
    }
    
    /**
    * Play / Stop exercising.
    *
    * @return {void}
    */
    function toggle()
    {
      if (playing)
      {
        pause();
      }
      else
      {
        loop();
      }
    }
    
    /**
    * Reset timer. <--SHOULD BE PAUSE
    *
    * @return {void}
    */
    function pause()
    {
      playing = false;
      setLabel("Paused");
      //setCounter('--')
      if (countdownTimer)
      {
        clearTimeout(countdownTimer); // FIGURE OUT HOW NOT TO CLEAR
      }
    }
    
    // TIMER FUNCTION
    /**
    * Timer loop function
    *
    * @return {void}
    */
    function loop()
    {
      playing = true;
    
      // Change button label
      setButtonText("Pause");
    
      // Get current exercise
      var exercise = workout.exercises[current];
    
      // If out of the exercises Array's bounds, call 'done'
      if (!exercise)
      {
        return done();
      }
      // Otherwise run countdown and update UI.
      countdown(exercise.duration, exercise.name, function ()
      {
        countdown(exercise.break, "Break", function ()
        {
          // Next exercise.
          current++;
          // Re-iterate until finished.
          loop();
        });
      });
    }
    
    /**
    * Exercise session is now over.
    *
    * @return {void}
    */
    function done()
    {
      pause();
      document.getElementById("feedbackScreen").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    /**
    * Recursive timer function.
    *
    * @param  {Number} seconds
    * @param  {String} label
    * @param  {Function} callback
    * @return {void}
    */
    function countdown(seconds, label, callback)
    {
      setLabel(label);
      setCounter(seconds);
    
      // Set timeout to next second
      countdownTimer = setTimeout(function ()
      {
        // Decrease seconds.
        seconds--;
    
        // Check whether the countdown is over - execute callback if so.
        if (seconds <= 0)
        {
          return callback();
        }
    
        // Call itself with a lower number otherwise.
        countdown(seconds, label, callback);
      }, 1000); // (1 sec).
    }
    
    /**
    * Set counter text.
    *
    * @param  {Number} val
    * @return {void}
    */
    function setCounter(val)
    {
      counter.innerHTML = val;
    }
    
    /**
    * Set label text.
    *
    * @param  {String} text
    * @return {void}
    */
    function setLabel(text)
    {
      if (label.textContent === text)
      {
        return;
      }
      label.innerHTML = text;
    }
    
    /**
    * Set button text.
    *
    * @param  {String} text
    * @return {void}
    */
    function setButtonText(label)
    {
      button.innerHTML = label;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="exerciseLabel"></div>
    <button id="pauseButton"></button>
    <div id="exerciseCounter"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: You are not saving any current playing exercise information, you'll need to store it when pausing and inquiring it when resuming/playing.

Comment: You can use a `window.localstorage` to store where the loop stopped; this might be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957249/how-can-i-show-alert-on-my-timer-when-timer-finished/46957728#46957728

Comment: I think you may be overcomplicating this functionality.  Why does the timer need to be recursive?

Comment: I need to confirm the basic functionality you desire.  If I am correct, you want to (1) start the exercise routine (each one for a specified duration), (2) if the user pauses during a particular exercise, you want to retain the current exercise and when resumed, complete the remaining duration of such prior to moving to the next exercise...therefore, you need to retain the current exercise index AND duration expired, when paused, then calculate the remaining duration when resumed prior to incrementing the next exercise index.  Is this true/accurate?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the issue was related to the refreshing of page. Actually, that is not the case. It is a matter of how the logic is implemented, meaning how you are storing the `current` index and reusing it. See below, my snippet.

Comment: @codemaker you are correct!

Comment: Here is my way of doing it. I hope that it helps despite being a different approach.  (I did make some assumptions prior to reading your reply).  https://www.methodpure.com/TimedExer.html

Comment: That's cool, how can I view the code without inspecting?

Comment: Not sure if you are still keeping your options open since you've accepted an answer.  You should be able to use a page save option in your browser (e.g. "File > Save Page As..."), but, if that is not available (i would be surprised if it isn't), then you should be able to select "View Source" from your browser and select the entire page and paste it to a text or code editor for saving as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var pause = false;
var displayBreak = false;

 window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
 };

 var count;
 var counter;
 var current = 0
var element = document.getElementById("exerciseLabel");
  var workout =
{
  "title": "Full Body",
  "exercises":
  [
    {
      "name": "Push Ups",
      "duration": 1,
      "break": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Squats",
      "duration": 2,
      "break": 0.5
    },
    {
      "name": "Running in place",
      "duration": 0.25,
      "break": 1
    }
  ]
};

 function initCounter() {
 
    count = workout.exercises[0].duration*60; 
    breakCount = workout.exercises[0].break*60;
    launchTimer();
  }

 function timer() {
    
    if(displayBreak){
      breakCount = breakCount - 1;
    }
    else{
    count = count -1;
    }
    
    var seconds = (displayBreak ? breakCount : count ) % 60;
    
    var minutes = Math.floor((displayBreak ? breakCount : count ) / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ""+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
    display();

   if(seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0)
    {
    //After duration of exercise or break
      if(!(current === workout.exercises.length - 1  && displayBreak === true)){
      // Display the next exercise or break
      displayBreak = !displayBreak;
      display();
        if(!displayBreak){
        current = current + 1 ;
        //set break duration
        breakCount = (workout.exercises[current].break)*60;
        }
        else{
        //set next exercise duration
        if(current < workout.exercises.length - 1){
        count = (workout.exercises[current + 1].duration)*60;
        }
        }
       }
      else
       {
        // All the exercises have already been displayed
        clearInterval(counter);
        pauseButton.innerHTML = "end";
       }   
     
      }
      
      }
      
function launchTimer(){
counter = setInterval(timer, 100); //(I put 100 to make it quick) 1000 will  run it every 1 second
}
  
function pauseOrResume(){
  pause = !pause
  if(pauseButton.innerHTML !== "end"){
    if(pause){
    clearInterval(counter);
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "resume"
  }
  else {
        launchTimer();
        pauseButton.innerHTML = "pause"
    }

  }
  }
  
  function display(){
    if(!displayBreak){
    element.innerHTML = workout.exercises[current].name
    }
    else{
    element.innerHTML = "break"
    }
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>


<div id="timer"></div>

<div id="exerciseLabel"></div>
<button id="pauseButton" onclick="pauseOrResume()">pause</button>
<div id="exerciseCounter"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: This is good and works, but the counter seems to be skipping the Break value?

Comment: @Brian, I updated the code taking into account the breaks. And you can even set a different duration for breaks and exercises

Comment: that's just beautiful. I am just confused by soemething... If the data being used is the JSON, why does the timer countdown from 5 seconds per exercise and break if the JSON value of each is 3?

Comment: first of all let me stress you have provided exactly what I was hoping for, so this question is just for me to understand better. What I don't understand is, when i run your code snipett, the timer shows seconds and decimals. When an exercise is displayed, like Push Ups, the countdown starts from 5 seconds, which is not the value specified in the JSON. But when a break is displayed, it counts down from 3 seconds, which is the correct value for breaks in the JSON. I was just unclear as to why this is happening.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Actually, I did not use the duration specified in the JSON for the countdown. I set only a global duration for exercise and another one for break.

Comment: I thought so, this is a problem for me as the timer is supposed to cycle through whatever values are specified in the JSON. But I think I can work through it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, the countdown iterates over duration of JSON for exercises and for breaks. I changed the value of the initial JSON so as to make the change noticeable.